# Xamarin.Forms ViewModel visited twice on Page load

Tags: c#, mvvm, model-binding

I have discovered it when debugging code on one of the ViewModels for my pages.

I have Page code behind like this:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        this.BindingContext = new ACheckPageViewModel();
    }

    public ACheckPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        ACheckPageViewModel viewmodel = new ACheckPageViewModel();
        //some code that needs viewmodel reference:
        if (viewmodel.SomeValue == "")
        {
            SomeValue.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

In OnAppearing I set binding context for everything I do between page and viewmodel.

In ACHeckPage() main method however I reference viewmodel again to set some properties on page that depend on viewmodels other values.

I could not access these xaml controls from viewmodel, that's why I referenced viewmodel again in main method.

I discovered that when I load page and debug the viewmodel, the breakpoints get visited twice.

Pages where I set Binding Context from XAML like this:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:FeaturedPageViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Don't load the viewmodel twice.

How can I alter Page's Control's properties depending on ViewModel other property without running through the code twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize it twice. Once in OnAppearing and once in the constructor. 
Try creating a property:

```
public ACheckPageViewModel VM {get; set;}
```

and OnAppearing set it like this:

```
VM  = new ACheckPageViewModel();
this.BindingContext = VM;
```

and after that you can use the VM property as you like if you need it.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me much trouble while loading pages. It was taking ages